# Strange FormView behavior....update stops working

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp:FormView control bound to a datasource.  Everything is working fine.

If I put the following code in the Init event:

```
Private Sub frmEdit_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles frmEdit.Init
   Debug.WriteLine(frmEdit.Controls.Count)
End Sub
```

.....the update no longer works (no exceptions, it just reloads itself with the old data.)

However, if I change it to this:

```
Private Sub frmEdit_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles frmEdit.Init
   Debug.WriteLine("hello world")
End Sub
```

....it works again.  So, the difference is that I am accessing the frmEdit.Controls in the first example.  My question is, why does this break it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a Control collection, you are triggering code ensuring that the child controls are initialized as well.  For a FormView, Init is far too early in the lifecycle for this.  You're initializing controls before the ViewState is ready, so the controls aren't going to be re-populated correctly.

You can access the controls later in the lifecycle and I think `frmEdit.Row.Controls` is what you're after.